# Convert a public key to GPG readable format

Tags: windows, encryption, gnupg, smartcard

For a backup scenario, I want to peform asymmetric encryption of the data. For this I'm using [duplicati (2.0)](http://www.duplicati.com/) paired with [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard).

Now I have a smartcard ([PKCS#11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) / [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Service_Provider) interface via [OpenSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSC)) on which I have a 2048-bit [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) private key. I have a copy of [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openssl) on my machine as well as [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) (which supports the usual formats [SSH2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Version_2.x) / [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) / DER) with private-key access.

My aim is to add the public key, corresponding to the private key as an encryption subkey to my existing software-based keyring with an 4096-bit primary software RSA key. It would also be sufficient to add it "normally" as "somebody else's public key".

Now my question is:
**How can I convert a PEM / SSH2 / DER encoded public key so that it will be accepted by GPG as a public RSA key?**

Please note: "The key formats serve different purposes" is not a valid answer

If you want to suggest "use gpgsm" as an answer, please document how to do so with duplicati.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional thought I've come up with a "quick and dirty" solution to this problem.

Duplicati requires the the program to be called "gpg.exe", there's no way around that. However, one is allowed to specify a path where to find the executable and one is allowed to fully customize the command-line parameters (main sub-program) and switches .

This allows one to specify a static (sub-path) where one would put gpgsm and all dependencies and **rename** `gpgsm.exe` to `gpg.exe`. Afterwards one just simply locally imports a self-signed certificate (created with XCA) for the encryption target.

Comment: This sounds like a clever use of the rarely used `gpgsm`. If this works out, this seems like something that should be reported upstream, asking for an option that allows calling a different GnuPG "implementation".